# Find the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of a matrix linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, diagonalization

So I've been given this in college :

Find all the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of the linear transformation $\textsf T : \textsf{M}_{2 \times 2}(\mathbb R) \to \textsf{M}_{2 \times 2}(\mathbb R)$ given by

$$\textsf{T}(M) = M + (aM)^t$$

($a$ being a real number).

Once done, find the $a$ values which make $\textsf T$ non-diagonizable.

Thanks and sorry if its hard to understand. I'm new to posting on this site and I'm still working on my english.

Comment: I've polished up your math-symbols a bit, and slightly edited your english. I hope I didn't destroy your meaning in any way.

Comment: Thanks!! I probably should learn to do that

Comment: [MathJax quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Hint: When an expression involves both a matrix and its transpose, examine what happens to symmetric and skew-symmetric matrices. That will get you at least a couple of eigenvectors.

Comment: Also: diagonal matrices are an especially interesting class of symmetric matrices to look at.

Answer (score 1):

if you map the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} x & y \\ z & w \end{pmatrix}$ to the vector $\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y  \\ z \\ w \end{pmatrix}$ then you may represent $T$ by:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 + a & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0     & 1 & a & 0 \\
0     & a & 1 & 0 \\
0     & 0 & 0 &  1+ a
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y \\
z \\
w
\end{pmatrix}
$$

which gives three eigenvalues equal to $1+a$ and one to $1-a$. the, former corresponding to the symmetric 2 x 2 matrices as eigenvectors, and the latter to scalar multiples of $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$. as to special eigenvalues you might want to begin by looking at $a \in \{0,\pm 1\}$.

Comment: Question,does an nxn matrix necessarily has n eigenvalues?

Comment: by definition such a matrix must have a characteristic equation of degree $n$. how many roots this equation has will depend on the field in which solutions are sought.

Answer (score 0):

Think about a matrix that upon left-multiplying with $M$ would give $M$ and another matrix that also upon left-multiplying with $M$ would give $a$ times the transpose of $M$, $M^t$. The transformation matrix is the sum of these two matrices.

Then for this matrix to be diagonalizable, the multiplicity of each eigenvalue must match the number of corresponding eigenvectors.